# Android giving an error while IOS does not in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, typescript, native

`Error while updating property 'borderBottomRightRadius' of a view managed by: RCTView

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

I understand what this error means, at least I thought at first. I thought I had just accidentally given the wrong value to borderBottomRightRadius. But when looking through my code I could not find my error. The weird thing is that it only happens on my android device.

I am using expo go to debug and test my code. The error I mentioned is not shown in the console but only appears on my android screen. There are a lot of error locations accompanied with the error, but none are locations of an actual file that I have in my project..

Github: https://github.com/notJustStevenz/MyCash

In VS code I used the find function to search through all my code for every instance I had used the 'border' css tag. Which gave me this

https://pastebin.com/v1FHkNk3
Preview:

```
27 results - 13 files
 
components\button\BackButton.tsx:
  22      align-items: center;
  23:     border-radius: 10px; 
  24  `;
 
components\button\RegularButton.tsx:
  18      padding: 20px; 
  19:     border-radius: 20px;
  20  `;
 ...
```

Like I said, it seems like all the values I gave are of the correct type.

I've also tried to erase or change all the values of the 'border' css tag but nothing changed. With that said, I am absolutely clueless.